# a weird face in bevel

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I tried to use a bevel modifier and then there one point in the object has weird face. I tried to erase each face and combine differently but no matter how, this shows up again. All faces are directing outside correctly.
How can I remove this black/gray face? Why this happens?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That is probably caused by that triangle fan. Try converting it two quads, and it may solve your problem. May also be caused by overlapping geometry

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos I tried that too, it changes slightly but the face is still there. but I could solve by limiting angle in the modifier. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't there a partially connected / deconnected face inside ? You could check that quickly by deselecting all in Edit mode and in Vertex / Edge selection mode running `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`M`.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it! If I limit bevel by angle in the modifier, the weird face disappears.

[image]